# Android database insert into specific row

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert

I have a database and i can insert into it and read from it fine, but this is my issue:

first of all i have two tables, table1 and table2. Both tables only have 1 column and 1 row. So i didn't set my Key to autoincrement. Basically i want to keep overwriiting that value in the row and column instead of adding many values how do i do this?

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_DATA = "create table table1 (_id integer primary key, " + "table1 text);";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_WIFI = "create table table2 (_id integer primary key, " + "table2 text);";
```

and my insert is:

```
db.insertOrThrow(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, value);
```

But for some reason this increments the key and adds many values where i just want to keep overwriting the first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally with SQL, you use UPDATE to change data in rows, and INSERT to create new ones. I never worked with SQLite, but I'd be surprised if there wasn't an update function beside that insert one.

Edit: Looking at the docs, replaceOrThrow might be just what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to either do a rawQuery using a WHERE clause, or use db.update, see [this](http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-database.html) post for reference.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want to do is an [update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) .